# XGBoost on databricks - outdated scala version

Tags: scala, xgboost, databricks

I am trying to follow along the xgboost example on databricks found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/xgboost.html)

Everything seems to work fine until I get to the actual training part:

```
val xgboostModelRDD = XGBoost.trainWithRDD(trainRDD, ...)
```

At this point I get an error. Since the stacktrace is rather short I'll paste it here:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.overrideParamsAccordingToTaskCPUs(XGBoost.scala:232)
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainWithRDD(XGBoost.scala:293)
```

After doing some research, It appears that the reason for that error is incompatible scala version. The databricks community edition cluster comes preconfigured with scala version 2.10. This [cannot be modified](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2846/how-to-change-the-scala-version.html).

Does that mean that it is impossible to run xgboost using the community edition, or is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the forum post that you linked to is slightly outdated. Databricks Community edition actually does allow you to choose the cluster's Scala version.

First, navigate to the clusters page and click on the blue "Create Cluster" button:

[image]

From the "Databricks Runtime Version" dropdown menu, you can pick a runtime version which contains your desired Scala and Spark versions:

[image]

Comment: You are right, It seems that the forum I was checking is indeed outdated and your solution seems to work. I will check that my xgboost problem is resolved with the new scala version, however I am accepting the answer anyway since it resolved the root issue